# Unable to send spring boot microservice logs to ELK stack

Tags: spring-boot, logging, microservices, elastic-stack, elk

I ran the following commands to setup ELK stack on my local machine :

```
docker run -e "discovery.type=single-node"  -d -it --name es -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch:7.2.0
docker run -d -it --name kibana --link es:elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 kibana:7.2.0
docker run -d -it --name logstash -p 5000:5000 logstash:7.2.0 --path.settings= -e 'input { tcp { port => 5000 codec => "json" } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost"] index => "micro-%{serviceName}"} }'
```

Then I have added logback dependencies and changed default logback.xml in my microservice to configure `LogstashTcpSocketAppender` as below :

```
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" value="[${springAppName},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>


    <!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

    <!-- Appender to log to console -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ​
    <appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>localhost:5000</destination>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc />
                <context />
                <logLevel />
                <loggerName />

                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "serviceName": "PchService"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>

                <threadName />
                <message />
                <logstashMarkers />
                <stackTrace />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ​
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Then sent few requests to the microservice. But when I open kibana at http://localhost:5601 no data/logs being sent to elastic search. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the service name to lower case to resolve the issue.